# Hooking into a BinaryWriter's Dispose

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, overriding, binarywriter

I would like to make writing more comfortable for a user of my class by offering them a BinaryWriter that, upon disposal, automatically adds its data to some internal queue.

For this purpose, I would like to write a subclass of BinaryWriter and override its Dispose method. However, `Dispose` is not virtual. Is it sufficient to hook into `Dispose(bool)`? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BinaryWriter.Dispose()` only contains a call to

```
   this.Dispose(true);
```

so overriding `Dispose(bool)` will work correctly.

Comment: +1 `Dispose()` is just a wrapper around the `IDisposable.Dispose(bool)` which is exactly the overload you want to override. Notice that `Dispose()` is public for external code consumption and `Dispose(bool)` is protected virtual. The reason is a bit obvious